# What are the best practices for Magento CRON (& cache cleaning)?

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, cron

I finally got CRON scheduling working properly (no thanks to Bluehost), and discovered a dizzying array of options--even more after I installed Aoe Scheduler and CacheCleaner.

Are the default CRON settings optimal/sufficient for most sites?

---

[image: CRON Default]

---

How beneficial is it to utilize CRON to regularly clear caches, or is this generally not necessary? Which caches would benefit most from regular renewal?

---

[image: Cache Cleaning]

---